# Django messages not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use Django's messages framework.

I've done exactly as told in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

I add messages by `messages.success(self.request, 'Updated.')` but no messages is shown. `{% if messages %}` evaluates as always false.

If I print `{{ messages }}` I get `<django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7fb701c47b70>`.

What can be wrong?

My middlewares

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

My template context processors

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.template.context_processors.debug",
    "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.template.context_processors.media",
    "django.template.context_processors.static",
    "django.template.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
]
```

My installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
)
```

## Edit

```
class ItemUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'item'
    form_class = ItemForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ItemUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["user"] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        with transaction.atomic(), reversion.create_revision():
            self.object = form.save()
            reversion.set_user(self.request.user)
            reversion.set_comment("Updating")
        messages.success(self.request, "Updated")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_update_url()
```

## Edit 2

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
                {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
                {{ message }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    no messages
{% endif %}
```

## Edit 3

This is a big mystery for me.

It doesn't add the message if I use

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    messages.success(self.request, "Updated")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

but it does add the message if I use

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.success(request, 'Updated.')
    return super(ItemUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual snippet where you add messages?

Comment: I've updated my question with the snippet

Comment: Everything seems to be ok with your configuration, i'd check instead if messages.success is actually called. Another thing that may be happening is that you're redirecting multiple times after success, so the message is lost in between.

Comment: I've edited my question. Of some reason it does work sometimes

Comment: Are you sure form_valid is called? Add `assert False` to it and make sure it is called.

Comment: Please double check - your code is OK.  The messages might have been rendered in a different browser tab//window/session.

Comment: @Jamgreen: Can you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing your messages in the template because form_valid returns an HttpResponse, which drops the request object on the floor.

Note how your solution *does* pass the request object forward.

```
return super(ItemUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What you could do to get around this is to make sure you always get the messages within the view and pass it as a context object. Then the response method won't matter.

```
from django.contrib import messages

class Homepage(View):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get(request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'messages': messages.get_messages(request)
        })

    def post(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It is OK to use `messages.success` from `form_valid`.

Comment: @Udi What are you talking about? That's neither the problem here nor what I was addressing. Of course he can use messages.success in form_valid! The message will just never show up if it's not tied to a request object in some way.

Comment: It is OK to return a redirect from form_valid.

Comment: @Udi Correct, but that is not without consequence. Hence this question.

Comment: You wrote "It's not working in form_valid", but messages.succes works in form_valid. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: the code in the question is perfectly OK.  The correct answer should be: "Your code is OK, messages.success could be used in form_valid".  I do not understand your answer, it does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Messages stored via message.success() will not render in your template if you return an HttpResponse object, unless you explicitly retrieve said messages via the context on the subsequent view, which is what my code block illustrates. I've explained myself and provided code-- I cannot make myself any clearer. If you don't understand what I'm saying, don't be so quick to call me out as being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this to help future users.

To resolve this issue, you must add a call to super() in the form_valid function:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    super().form_valid(form) # if Python 3, else super(ItemUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
    ...
```